# How to get first and last date of a half year

Tags: vb.net, datetime

From any date in the year. So either
1st Jan, 30 jun, 1st July, 31st of Dec

I have this code for quarters, how to convert it to half year??

```
        'To get the first day of the quarter
        Public Shared Function FirstDayOfQuarter(ByVal theDay As DateTime) As DateTime
            Dim currQuarter As Integer = (Month(theDay) - 1) \ 3 + 1
            Dim FirstDayQuarter As DateTime = DateSerial(Year(theDay), 3 * currQuarter - 2, 1)
            Return FirstDayQuarter
        End Function
        'To get the last day of the quarter
        Public Shared Function LastDayOfQuarter(ByVal theDay As DateTime) As DateTime
            Dim currQuarter As Integer = (Month(theDay) - 1) \ 3 + 1
            Dim LastDayQuarter As DateTime = DateSerial(Year(theDay), 3 * currQuarter + 1, 0)
            Return LastDayQuarter
        End Function
```

Comment: The logic for a half would be the same as for a quarter, with only the numbers changing. If you understand the code you posted then it should be easy to change the numbers to work, so I can only assume that you haven't bothered to understand that code. In that case, it's too soon to be asking a question here. Understand the code, make your best attempt and then, if it doesn't work, you have a question serpent asking here.

Answer (score 0):

You could write

```
'To get the first day of the half year
Public Shared Function FirstDayOfHalf(ByVal theDay As DateTime) As DateTime
    Dim FirstDayHalf As DateTime = DateSerial(Year(theDay), If((theDay.Month > 6), 7, 1), 1)
    Return FirstDayHalf
End Function
'To get the last day of the half year
Public Shared Function LastDayOfhalf(ByVal theDay As DateTime) As DateTime
    Dim LastDayHalf As DateTime = DateSerial(Year(theDay), If((theDay.Month > 6), 13, 7), 0)
    Return LastDayHalf
End Function
```

Which result on

For today 01.10.2023 with

```
    Debug.Write(FirstDayOfHalf(Now))
    Debug.Write(LastDayOfhalf(Now))
    Debug.Write(FirstDayOfHalf(Now.AddMonths(-6)))
    Debug.Write(LastDayOfhalf(Now.AddMonths(-6)))
```

The result will be

```
01.07.2023 00:00:00
31.12.2023 00:00:00
01.01.2023 00:00:00
30.06.2023 00:00:00
```